Inflation map in the first group cohomology
Let $C_p$ be the cyclic group of odd prime order $p.$ Consider the group $G=C_p \times C_p$ given by $\langle a, b \mid a^p=b^p=1 \rangle$. All the size $p$ subgroups of $G$ are denoted by $H_i= \langle (a, b^i) \rangle$ for $i=0, \cdots, p-1$ and $K = \langle (1, b)\rangle.$ Consider the quotient homomorphism $\pi_i: G \to G/H_i.$
Let us consider the trivial $G$-module $\mathbb{Z}/p=\langle x \mid x^p=1\rangle.$ Then $\pi_i$ induces map
$$\pi_i^\ast : Hom_{group}(G/H_i, \mathbb{Z}/p) \to Hom_{groups}(G, \mathbb{Z}/p).$$
Here $Hom_{groups}(A, B)$ denotes the set of all group homomorphisms from $A$ and $B$. Note that it will be an abelian group, and $\pi_i^\ast$  is a group homomorphism. Note that the first group cohomology
$$H^1(A, \mathbb{Z}/p) \cong Hom_{groups}(A, \mathbb{Z}/p).$$
Under the identifications, $Hom_{group}(G/H_i, \mathbb{Z}/p)\cong \mathbb{Z}/p = \langle f \rangle$ and $Hom_{group}(G, \mathbb{Z}/p)=  \mathbb{Z}/p \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p=\langle g,h \rangle$, I am guessing
$$\pi_i^\ast(f) = g-ih.$$
Any help will be appreciated in justifying the above guess.

Your question is ill-defined, because the identifications $Hom(G,\mathbb{Z}/p)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\times \mathbb{Z}/p$ and $Hom(G/H_i,\mathbb{Z}/p)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p$ depends of the choices of generators.
Note also that all subgroups of order $p$ of $G$ are not necessarily one of the $H_i$'s, but I will stick to these ones.
In order to make sense of your question, I will consider that we choose $\overline{(1,b)}$ as a generator of $G/H_i$.
The isomorphism $Hom(G/H_i,\mathbb{Z}/p)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p$ sends a morphism $\psi:G/H_i\to\mathbb{Z}/p$ to $\psi(\overline{(1,b)})$.
Note that the inverse map sends $\overline{m}$ to the morphism $\overline{(1,b)}^k\in G/H_i\mapsto \overline{k} \overline{m}\in\mathbb{Z}/p$
We will also use the identification  $Hom(G,\mathbb{Z}/p\times\mathbb{Z}/p)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\times\mathbb{Z}/p$ which sends $\varphi:G\to\mathbb{Z}/p$ to $(\varphi(a,1),\varphi(1,b))$.
Note that, since your coefficients is an abelian group, and all the actions are trivial, and we have an equality $H^1(G/H_i,\mathbb{Z}/p)=Hom(G/H_i,\mathbb{Z}/p)$.
Note also that $\pi_i^*$ is just right composition by $\pi_i$.
By definition of $H_i$, we have $\pi_i((a^k,b^\ell))=\overline{(1,b^{\ell-ki})}\in G/H_i$.
Hence, if $\psi:G/H_i\to \mathbb{Z}/p$, we have  $\pi_i^*(\psi)(a^k,b^\ell)=\psi(\overline{(1,b^{\ell-ki})})=\psi(\overline{(1,b)})^{\ell-ki}$.
Under the previous identification, it corresponds to $(\psi(\overline{(1,b)})^{-i},\psi(\overline{(1,b)}))$.
All in all, your map is $\pi_i^*:\overline{k}\mapsto(-\overline{k}\overline{i},\overline{k})$.
With your notation, you will get $f\mapsto -ig+h$ (at least if $g$ corresponds to the first coordinate and $h$ to the second.
